# Non capturing group to parse git status

Tags: regex, git

I'm trying to build a regex to match any .c or .h pattern whithin modified file of git status -s.

(Find the regex here: 
[regexr.com/40afj](https://regexr.com/40afj) )

```
(?:M).*.[c|h]
```

to be used on this king of data:

```
M  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.c
M  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.c
M  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.h
M  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.h
??  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.c
??  fjdkls/fjdkslm/djks.c
```

Can you explain me why the M is matching even if it is in a non-capturing group?

The expected result is to match full path of modified file.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Do you know what a (non-)capturing group is?

Comment: Looks like you need `^M(.*\.[ch])$`, see https://regexr.com/40ah3. Note that *caprturing* still *matches*, consumes, i.e. adds the matched text to the overall match value.

Comment: (OT: If you want a list of modified files, you can use `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M HEAD` instead of parsing `git status`.)

Comment: Thanks Biffen that solve the problem, but I'm still curious about capturing group. I have misudunderstand capturing group after reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do how can I retrieve only one group with grep for example?

Comment: Don't parse the output of `git status -s`, but rather the one of `git status --porcelain` which is guaranteed to remain stable in the future (but other than that essentially the same).

Answer (score 1):

Non Capturing group means that it isn't captured when regexp matches. Here the only group that you need is the one that matches file path:

```
[ ADMRCU?!]{2} (.+\.[ch])
```

With such regexp the only captured group will contain file path. Moreover what you should use is `--porcelain` instead of `-s`. `--porcelain` is meant to be more stable and it should be used for scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is only matching the ones beginning with M because the Regex is specifically looking for M.

If you add a quantifier(?) after the first group that should work.

```
(?:M)?.*.[c|h]
```

Non-capturing groups group tokens together without creating a capture group, they do not look over the contents. If you want to capture everything except the M then you need to put everything in a capture group.

```
(?:.*?)[^\s]+(.*\.[c|h])
```

This will match but not capture the group containing M and capture the full path excluding the non-capturing group.